# Using Bitbucket App Password in Yocto recipe for git repo over https

Tags: bitbucket, yocto, yocto-recipe

On command line "git clone https://username:app-password@bitbucket.org/dir/repo.git", works, wherein app-password is an "alphanumeric string created by bitbucket"

But when using with Yocto Recipe SRC_URI = "git://**username:app-password**@bitbucket.org/workspace/repo.git;protocol=https;"

gives error: "fatal: could not read the password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': No such device or address".

Please advise how to use bitbucket app-passwords in the Yocto recipe for pulling git repo over https method?

Comment: Why don't you use ssh keys instead?

Comment: they are removing ssh keys support

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to solve this with:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.org/myworkspace/myrepo.git;protocol=https;user=myusername:my-app-password;"
```

Note that the username should not be your email address but your Bitbucket **username**.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: which branch of yocto did u test with? the above solution doesn't solve my issue. I am using dunfell branch of yocto.

Comment: @SatishJadhav I am using Dunfell as well.

Comment: it worked for me using Zeus